# Pass multiple onclick handler functions to child component

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-props

I have some code below to show the issue. There are two handleClick functions that I want to pass to a child component.

The issue is that each handler will trigger from a separate button element. I don't need both functions to trigger at the same time.

I've tried putting both functions in a single handlerClickOneAndTwo function but that is not correct since I don't want that single function to trigger both handlers.

How can I send both of these handler functions down to the child component?

```
    const handleClickOne = (e) => {
        //some handler logic
        }));
    };

    const handleClickTwo = (e) => {
        //some handler logic
    };

    return (
        <ChildComponent
            onClick={handleClickOne}
    //I also want to handleClickTwo here but it will trigger from a different button
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass different props for diffrent `onClick`. Like this:

```
const handleClickOne = (e) => {
        //some handler logic
        }));
    };

    const handleClickTwo = (e) => {
        //some handler logic
    };

    return (
        <ChildComponent
            onClick1={handleClickOne}
            onClick2={handleClickTwo}
        />
    );
```

and in your child component assign these according to you requirement

Comment: Not sure why I was thinking the "onClick" prop name was a requirement. This is the correct answer, thanks!